# Need to create multiple HUDSON_HOME environment variables with different name for multiple hudson instance

Tags: hudson

I have 2 Hudson instances deployed in single tomcat. For that i need to set different Hudson home directories. 1st hudson has home directory set as HUDSON_HOME(D:\Hudson) and its working fine.
In 2nd hudson, i have tried to change the name HUDSON_HOME to HUDSON_HOME_BOSS in web.xml & set HUDSON_HOME_BOSS as D:\hudson_boss in environment variables but it is still taking the location d:\hudson.

DOes anyone has any idea how to change hudson home directory with different name???

Comment: Why do you want two separate instances of Hudson running under the same instance of Tomcat? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

HUDSON_HOME is the environment variable that you need to set. You cannot change its name. Try setting HUDSON_HOME to different directories on each instance's web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this is a bit old but will assume you're still looking for the answer. Go here and you will find out how easy it is: http://www.jamesthigpen.com/blog/2009/04/17/running-multiple-hudson-instances-simultaneously/

I actually had to have two instances running a few days ago.